# How do you disable the "A leading decimal point can be confused with a dot: '.1'" rule from the jshint extension in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

JS hint is highlighting this in my js files in VS code, I like being able to write .5 instead of 0.5 in some situations so would like the freedom to disable this rule.

Is that possible? Perhaps in the .jshintrc file but I have been having issues finding anything about it.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: If you switch to ESLint (JSLint is a very old library at this point) you can [switch the rule off completely](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-floating-decimal).

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thank you for the quick response. Does the jshint extension (dbaeumer.jshint) use the JSLint library to work it's magic? If so, does your comment indicate their is no possible way to do this? If so (and I am new to SO), you could write that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: [Looks like it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint). The only reason I mentioned moving to ESLint is that JSHint (almost 15 years old now I think) is _extremely_ opinionated (like it's author Doug Crockford, lol). Anyway, ESLint is much more configurable which, if you're working on modern JS applications, is much more preferable as it gives you much more control over the warnings you get from your code. The alternative is Prettier, but again, very opinionated.

Comment: I do have prettier also but really downloaded that as a formatter. Not interested in it linting (even though formatting is linting technically). I just wanted a piece of software that will pick up on my "grammatical" errors in my code, looks like ESLint is the way to go. I couldn't see if Doug Crockford had any input in the JSHint extension but agree it does seem to be quite opinionated and not configurable (a perfect storm of a bad extension in my opinion). Cheers for the help. Edit: Shall I leave the question open on the off chance there is a way to do it?

Comment: Don't see why not. There are people who may have encountered this before. Best of luck with your coding.